# Bash: Incorrect substring in for loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I'm trying to write a script to check if a string is a palindrome

```
read str
l=${#str}-1
isPal=1

for((i=0;i<=l/2;i++))
do
    echo "${str:$i,1} :: ${str:$((l-i)),1}"          
    if [[ ${str:$i,1} -ne ${str:$((l-i)),1} ]]; then
            isPal=0
    fi
done

if [[ $isPal -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "YES"
else
        echo "NO"
fi
```

for an input string: *abcdefghi*

output is:

```
cdefghi :: bcdefghi
cdefghi :: bcdefghi
cdefghi :: bcdefghi
cdefghi :: bcdefghi
cdefghi :: bcdefghi
YES
```

I can't understand what's happening with the substring. I expect it to return me the ith character and the (l-i)th character respectively

Answer (score 1):

You have at least a couple of errors:

1. `l=${#str}` is going to give you a string result like `5-1`, not `4`. Use `l=$((${#str} - 1))`.
2. In an arithmetic context, `x,y` evaluates `x`, disregards the result, and expands to the evaluation of `y`. Instead of `${str:$i,1}`, use `${str:i:1}`. `${str:l-i:1}` is sufficient, since `l-i` is already being evaluated in an arithmetic context.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `,` instead of `:` to delimit the substring.

And `-ne` instead of `!=` to compare.

So this code will work:

```
if [[ ${str:$i:1} != ${str:$((l-i)):1} ]]; then
```

Test 1:

```
abcdefghi
a :: i
b :: h
c :: g
d :: f
e :: e
NO
```

Test 2:

```
abcdedcba
a :: a
b :: b
c :: c
d :: d
e :: e
YES
```